# how to avoid getRuntime.exec() to block when reading inputStream?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I call a class which is located somewhere in a jar file (using java -classpath path/file.jar classname) within my java code.

My problem is when the command `genKOSCommand` is invalid the call to `input.readLine()` will block the program. So I added `input.ready()` to hope avoiding blocking. When I debug the program it's ok. Seem to work. But when don't run it in debug the buffer is never ready.

```
        // Execute a command with an argument that contains a space
        String[] genKOSCommand = new String[] {
                "java",
                "-classpath",
                Config.XDSI_TEST_KIT_HOME + "/xdsitest/lib/xdsitest.jar;"
                        + Config.XDSI_TEST_KIT_HOME + "/xdsitest/classes",
                "ca.etsmtl.ihe.xdsitest.docsource.SimplePublisher", "-k",
                "C:/Softmedical/Viewer_Test/xdsi-testkit-2.0.4/xdsihome/usr/data/image14.dcm" };

        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(genKOSCommand);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                child.getInputStream()), 13107200);

        String line = null;

        if (input.ready()) {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            try {
                child.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Any advice on how to detect problems with the executed command?

Thank you.

Comment: this has been answered many times before, the canonical article is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: As I suggested in your previous question, you can use different threads to read from each stream.

Comment: @MByD so if I start threads to read the streams this will only avoid blocking my main process. But readLine will still block the thread, doesn't it? (repeat)

Comment: the link only tells me to RTFM and to have different threads for each stream, still not enough.

Comment: @code-gijoe - what exactly are you missing then?  you read the streams in a separate thread.  in the main thread, you wait for the process to finish.  if it's an invalid command, it should finish pretty quickly and give you an non-zero result from the `waitFor()` method.

Comment: I was just wondering why wouldn't it just freeze the tread as it does with the main process.

Comment: @code-gijoe - what happens when you try it?  (btw, don't use `input.ready()` that won't help and isn't useful)

Answer (score -2):

You need to wait in a loop for the BufferedReader to be ready.

```
while (input.ready() == false) { /* intentional empty space here */ }

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
/* rest of code follows */
```